# オラクルSQLで列名を別名で表示させる方法

Tags: sql, oracle

今の所、下記二つの方法を試したのですが
エラーが発生してしまいます。
列名を別名で表示させる方法をご存知の方がいればお伺いしたいです。

```
select worker.empno ||',' || worker.ename|| ',' ||  
worker.hiredate||','|| mgr.ename "Employee Number, Employee Name,Hiredate, Mgr Name."
from emp worker , emp mgr
where worker.mgr=mgr.empno;
```

エラー文
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long

```
select worker.empno AS EmployeeNumber,worker.ename,worker.hiredate,mgr.ename
from emp worker , emp mgr
where worker.mgr=mgr.empno;
```

エラー文
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/112101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前者のSQLは`AS`が省略されていますが`"Employee Number, Employee Name,Hiredate, Mgr Name."`という50文字の識別子になっています。

Oracle 12.2以前では、30文字を超える識別子は付けられません。
12.2以降は128バイトまで識別子に使えるため`ORA-00972`は出なくなります。
[本家SOの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085571)

後者のSQLは私の環境ではエラーが再現できませんでした。
改行が入っておらず`mgr.ename`と`from`がくっついていたり、全角スペースが混入していないでしょうか？

Comment: 後者のSQL文、上手くいきました。ありがとうございます。EmployeeNumberをEmployee　Numberとして空白を空けてしまって入力していたことが原因でした。